# PHP Lithium - Authentication how to access session data

Tags: php, lithium

I have read about authentication in Lithium manual, still I have some questions about it.
After `Auth::check ('default', $this->request)`, it will return an array of user data if succeed. I have finished this part according to the manual.

1. if I want to save some of this array into session (not all of them), how to do it?
2. Are those data in session encrypted? If not, how could I manipulate it, I want to encrypt it for security concern.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you something to go on regarding encrypting session data - http://nitschinger.at/Session-Encryption-with-Lithium.

As far as telling `Auth::check()` which fields to save to the session:

```
Auth::config(array(
   'default' => array(
       'session' => array(
           'persist' => array('username', 'email')
        )
    )
));
```

This is in the latest master, and there is more explanation at the top of `security\Auth.php`.